# assign the javascript code by a javascript function

Tags: javascript

For some reason, I have to assign the javascript code by a javascript function, like the code at below.

```
<html>
     <head>
    <script>
        window.onload = init();
        function init(){

            document.getElementsByName('content')[0] = alert('LOL');

        }
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" name="content">


    </script>
     </head>
     <body>

     </body>
</html>
```

After page load, the expected result should like following

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('LOL');

    </script>
     </head>
     <body>

     </body>
</html>
```

However, the alertbox doesn't display. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Why do you want this? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: OK what is really going on here?

Comment: Improve your sample quality, mistakes on both script tags and in getElemen***t***sById. We can't edit so few chars...

Answer (score 2):

To get you started:

- Don't misspell script
- Don't misspell elements
- There is no `name` attribute for script elements
- `onload = foo()` will call `foo` immediately and assign its return value to `onload`. Get rid of the `()`
- Browsers (AFAIK) won't respect modifications to existing script elements, only new ones. So use `createElement` and `appendChild`

Answer (score 0):

Write this instead:

```
window.onload = function init(){
  document.getElementsByName('content')[0] = 'LOL';
  alert('LOL');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the text of the javascript tag won't make it execute, because it is in the client side. I would do it more like this:

```
    window.onload = init();
    function init(){

        document.getElementsByName('content')[0] = function SomeMethod(){ alert('LOL'); };
        SomeMethod();
    }
```